# Unable to make Google OAuth2 work on CakePHP 3 app

Tags: php, angularjs, cakephp, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

First of all, thanks to anyone who will look into this with me. Let me just say that I am a CakePHP beginner. Although my website is functional, it is relatively simple thus I did not gain much knowledge of the framework from developing it. Let's say, I'm a basic user with a less basic problem...!

So, I'm currently developing a website with AngularJS and CakePHP 3. The CakePHP part is a REST API, and of course, the Angular, the client side of the website.

Some of the pages should only be accessed by registered/logged in users, or at least users which email matches @mydomain.com (who then should be registered).

At fisrt, the API/site were designed to deal with this through HTTP Basic authentication but two days ago I got asked to deal with it through a Google OAuth2 Authentication.

So I've tried looking around if anyone had done that on CakePHP3 yet, without a plugin (someone mentioned to me the CakeDC/users plugin, but the documentation is so poor that I didn't go there...). I found these :

http://caketuts.key-conseil.fr/index.php/2015/05/22/integrer-lapi-oauth2-de-google-avec-cakephp-v3/ (in French, sorry, but the code is pretty clear)

http://blog.jainsiddharth21.com/2013/04/29/login-with-google-in-cakephp/ (which is understandable but not really what I chose to do, but still usefull and close to my code)

Although my code is pretty much 90% like this first link, I can't seem to get the Authentication working the way it is supposed to.

Here is my code :

### AppController.php :

```php
public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');

    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'googlelogin',
        ],
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'authError' => __("You don't have rights for this page"),
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'forbidden'
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'myHomePage',
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'googlelogin'
        ]
    ]);
}
```

### UsersController.php

```php
public function googlelogin() {

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId(GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setRedirectUri(GOOGLE_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI);

    $client->setScopes(array(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    ));
    $url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    $this->redirect($url);
}

public function confirmLogin() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId(GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setRedirectUri(GOOGLE_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI);

    $client->setScopes(array(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    ));
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');

    if (isset($this->request->query['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate($this->request->query['code']);
        $this->request->Session()->write('access_token', $client->getAccessToken());
    }

    if ($this->request->Session()->check('access_token') && ($this->request->Session()->read('access_token'))) {
        $client->setAccessToken($this->request->Session()->read('access_token'));
    }

    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
        $this->request->Session()->write('access_token', $client->getAccessToken());
        $oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
        $user = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
        try {
            if (!empty($user)) {
                if (preg_match("/(@mydomain\.com)$/", $user['email'])) {
                        $result = $this->Users->find('all')
                            ->where(['email' => $user['email']])
                            ->first();
                    if ($result) {
                        $this->Auth->setUser($result->toArray());
                        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                    } else {

                        $data = array();
                        $data['email'] = $user['email'];
                        $data['first_name'] = $user['givenName'];
                        $data['last_name'] = $user['familyName'];
                        $data['socialId'] = $user['id'];
                        //$data matches my Users table

                        $entity = $this->Users->newEntity($data);
                        if ($this->Users->save($entity)) {
                            $data['id'] = $entity->id;
                            $this->Auth->setUser($data);
                            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                        } else {
                            $this->Flash->set('Logging error');
                            $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->set('Forbidden');
                    $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
                }
            } else {
                $this->Flash->set('Google infos not found');
                $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->Flash->set('Google error');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
        }
    }
}
```

I also added the following lines to the file

### paths.php

```php
define('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID', 'My_client_id');
define('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET', 'My_client_secret');
define('GOOGLE_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI', 'mylinkto/confirmLogin');
```

In Chrome's debugging tool, it seems that confimLogin is called (twice by the way) with a valid code as query parameter, and then googlelogin is called. So I end up on the log page every time...

I feel like there must be something I'm missing here. Does anyone have any idea? (Thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should allow your login method in Auth component so that action to these method not get redirected again to googlelogin method

```
$this->Auth->allow(['googlelogin','confirmLogin']);
```

Comment: So I tried that, adding it to the AppController initialize method and/or a beforeFilter in my UsersController, but no change. googlelogin is still called after confirmLogin. Did I do this wrong ?

Comment: Found the issue! The allow parameter need to be an array :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

reacting to your comment about our documentation, we've added a detailed step by step tutorial about [how to configure CakeDC/Users to use Google login in CakePHP](https://www.cakedc.com/jorge_gonzalez/2016/10/11/login-with-google-oauth2-in-cakephp-using-cakedc-users-plugin):

1. Use composer to install the CakeDC Users Plugin and the required oauth2 providers

To be able to configure the callbacks in Google dashboard, you'll need to create a virtual host for you application. You don't need a working domain name, you could use something like "mydomain.dev" but Google requires a domain name (no localhost).

```
composer require cakedc/users:@stable 
composer require league/oauth2-google:@stable
```

2. Load it from your bootstrap.php file

   Plugin::load('CakeDC/Users', ['routes' => true, 'bootstrap' => true]);
3. Run migrations to add 2 new tables: 'users' and 'social_accounts'

```
bin/cake migrations migrate -p CakeDC/Users
```

4. Load the Component in your src/Controller/AppController.php

   public function initialize()
   {
       parent::initialize();
       //
       // ...
       //
       $this->loadComponent('CakeDC/Users.UsersAuth');
   }
5. Create a new Google application

   - Go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard and create a new google+ application
   - You can follow the datailed instructions (screenshots included) here: [Step by step create google app for social login Oauth2](https://www.cakedc.com/jorge_gonzalez/2016/10/11/create-google-app-for-web-oauth2-login-step-by-step)
6. Once you get your client id and client secret strings, add the following configuration file under /config/users.php, and paste your client id and secret. Trim any blank space in the codes before paste.

   // /config/users.php file contents
   $config = [
       'Users.Social.login' => true,
       'OAuth.providers.google.options.clientId' => 'CLIENT_ID_HERE',
       'OAuth.providers.google.options.clientSecret' => 'SECRET_HERE',
   ];

   return $config;
7. Modify your bootstrap.php file to ensure the config file is loaded this way

   Configure::write('Users.config', ['users']); //add this line before Plugin::load('CakeDC/Users...
   Plugin::load('CakeDC/Users', ['routes' => true, 'bootstrap' => true]);

This file will override any configuration key present in the Plugin, you can check the configuration options here Configuration.

**Done!**

Now you are ready to go to your login page and click "Sign up with Google".

Comment: Wow nice! Will definitely try that on my next project, thanks. This will also probably help many others.

Comment: nice, but what is the link to the sign on page? I can see it in the plugin how do you link to it?

Comment: I think I am missing the code that goes into the plugin folder, it does not seems that composer is generating it, is there a github link where I can download it? thank you

Comment: @gabrielkolbe we've created an example repo with the plugin setup, please also note this answer is old and we've upgraded the plugin to use the latest CakePHP 4 version and best practices https://github.com/CakeDC/users-example/tree/9.next

Comment: I've installed this but I need to log in again every time I go back to my site. Is the session length based on the "token" variable in users.php?

Comment: the token variable handles the expiration time of the validate email and reset password tokens as far as I remember